# How do I use an "Arrow Storm"?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I have a boatload of assassins now, which gives me 3 "Assassin Bars". I now see an option that says "Assassinate/Arrow Storm", but every time I call the assassins only one shows up and they don't seem to be using arrows or any more powerful. For reference I'm playing on the PC and "T" is the button I'm pressing to call assassins.

Comment: On Xbox, you had to hold the button when you had three full gauges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stand near an enemy and then hold the <kbd>T</kbd> key (the one that's used to call recruits) until death falls on your enemies.

This video demonstrates it (not on PC):

Comment: Check for video, and because it looks like you were first.  Can't wait to rain arrows on my enemies. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Just Hold.

When playing Assassin's Creed Brotherhood, just **hold** down the button you use to call Assassins to get Arrow Storm.
In your case, the <kbd>T</kbd> button.
This brings down a rain of arrows killing *every enemy nearby*.